# How do I get fwrite() to not print to the page?

Tags: php

I'm using `fwrite()` to write a file, however, every time it runs, it prints all of the information to the webpage it's on and writes to the file, too. I'd rather it not echo it to the page.

Alright, I've retrieved the code. Here it is:

```
fwrite($data_file, "Confirmation Data: \r\n\r\n Song: " . $input_song . "\r\nFile1: " . $file_var1 . "\r\nFile2: " . $file_var2 . "\r\nFile3: " . $file_var3 . "\r\nFile4: " . $file_var4 . "\r\nExplanation Text: " . $input_explanation);
```

Whenever I run this, it outputs everything in the second place of `fwrite()` onto the page, so it outputs the follow onto the page, except with the variables replaced for their values:

Confirmation Data: \r\n\r\n Song: " . $input_song . "\r\nFile1: " . $file_var1 . "\r\nFile2: " . $file_var2 . "\r\nFile3: " . $file_var3 . "\r\nFile4: " . $file_var4 . "\r\nExplanation Text: " . $input_explanation

Comment: you should post your code

Comment: @Jamil We beg for code and you give us one line? What about what surrounds that line, is it inside a function? where do you call it?

Comment: Unless `$data_file` is `STDOUT`, this would normally not happen... My wild guess is some debugging code is overlooked...

Comment: You may have to post _more_ code, @Jamil

Comment: Alright, I'll do that soon. There's not much more, just a `fopen()` and some variables which work fine. I didn't use an `fclose()`, however, would that cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code, so we can follow it but most probably you are also echoing out the code as HTML in your PHP file and this is why it prints out on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You said your information is being echoed and not written to file. Perhaps you are using `echo` instead of using file related functions. However, without access to your code, I can only post **how** to write information to a file in PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);//display  all errors
ini_set('display_errors', true);


$filename = "testfile.txt";//the name of your output file

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');//create a filehandler - fh) and open the file in write mode

$string = "ABCDEFGH\n";//test string to write to the file
$myvar = fwrite($fh, $string);

$string = "IJKLMNO\n";//update the string variable with new data
fwrite($fh, $string);//write more data - can be repeated ad -infinitum

fclose($fh);//finally, close the file
```

But, if you truly want definitive answers, **post your code** so that we may be able to help you.

Comment: I understand. I thought it was a common problem. It does write to the file, but it also prints to the page. Apparently a function of `fwrite`, is to echo the information written to the page as well. I was wondering how to turn that off.

Comment: When I briefly wrote php regularly, I don't ever remember having that problem. The `fwrite` method should be analogous to the C standard library method which *I know* doesn't have that problem.

Comment: That's what I thought it should do, too. I went ahead and posted the code. I can't figure out why it doesn't just write without echoing to the page.